# out.write with android EditText

Tags: java, android

I have many out.write lines of code (515 in total) that build an excel.xml file.  I now need to be able to build a out.write line of code to include values from a string.  Here is an out.write code line

```
out.write ("    <Cell ss:StyleID=\"s44\"><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">25</Data><NamedCell ss:Name=\"Print_Area\"/></Cell>\r\n");
```

and I would like to replace the 25 with the string value square_area_feet_result

```
double square_area_feet = square_area_inches / sqin_to_sqft;
String square_area_feet_result = String.format("%.4f", square_area_feet);
m1_sa_ft.setText(square_area_feet_result);
```

the out.write seems quite literal so maybe I have to first build everything after out.write?

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: I would like to have out.write write both the fixed text as shown and the value of a string.  My example shows 25 within the data being writtten and instead I would rather have whatever the string square_area_feet_result contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i get it well, then the answer may be this :

```
out.write ("    <Cell ss:StyleID=\"s44\"><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">" + square_area_feet_result + "</Data><NamedCell ss:Name=\"Print_Area\"/></Cell>\r\n");
```

Regards,

Comment: I am going to give this a try right now.  it would be great if it is this easy!

Comment: update I think I have a misunderstanding of private and public strings?  Your solution seems to work but I am getting the word null where the 25 should be and this is wrong and it makes excel not open the .xml file.  If I manually edit the file on the PC and replace null with a number then excel opens the file so the syntax in java is correct it just is not picking of the value thus my thoughts about public and private.  Back to learning, I will accept your answer as soon as I fix my problem.  thank you, so far

Comment: Try debugging in with breakpoints looking at variables. Make sure square_area_feet_result is set before the out.write and then, there's no reason it's not working.
Let me know if you need more help debugging ;)

Comment: debugging is true in the manifest but I never see variables in the eclipse window on the top right while in the debug perspective.  this look like a great aid but I cant get it to work.

Comment: I break after the calculations and see all the correct values.  now I am going toggle that breakpoint and put one right bfore the out.write and see the value is there, brb.

Comment: when I break during the out.write there are no variables displayed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4726/discussion-between-wmburkert-and-kentino)